# changing the logo displayed in the tabs browser don't work in vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my `index.html`:

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel='icon' href="public\img\favicon.png">
            <title>ContreversyMedia</title>
          <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" /></link>-->
          </head>
          <body>
            <noscript>
              <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
            </noscript>
            <div id="app"></div>
            <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
          </body>
        </html>
```

I am trying to change the default logo displayed in the tabs browser:

[image: this logo I want to change that]

This is my public folder:

[image: folder hierachy]

But the problem is I remove pwa file in my project and delete all icon in public\img\icons but the dev tool still show file located to that place but my folder is empty I deleted my browser cache changed the bowser but the same result:

[image: this the vue default image displayed in my tabs next to the title of the app]

I don't know how to handle that since I'm not used to vuejs and how its template work.

Comment: You question is not clear enough. You should explain a little better what you are aiming for.

Comment: Your index.html sets your favicon to `"public\img\favicon.png"`, point this to your icon and it should all work fine

Comment: still don't work  with "public\img\favicon.png"

Answer (score 0):

Static assets (files under `public/`) are served from the base URL, so your `href` URL should not include `public/`. Also it looks like the icon is in `public/img/icons`, but your `href` does not specify the `icons` subdirectory.

Assuming a Vue CLI scaffolded project, your `href` should look like this:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>img/icons/favicon.png">
```

Comment: <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>img/icons/favicon.png"> this did'nt work

Answer (score 0):

On your folder structure print screen I seen that your `index.html` file is under the same folder as your `favicon.png` (`/public/img/icons/`), so the Vue will create automatically a brand new `index.html` for you and all changes that you make in your `index.html` will be ignored.

To fix this problem you will need to put your `index.html` in the root of your `public` folder (will be `/public/index.html`), and use the path `<%= BASE_URL %>img/icons/favicon.png` in your favicon import (`<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>img/icons/favicon.png">`)